# How to Group Data by week in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have data starting from date `01/02/2011` and get updated every day.

i want to format data using week starting from date `01/02/2011`.

I have entities

```
public DateTime? MeasurementDate { get; set; }
```

FORMAT OF DATE:`2011-02-01 00:00:00.0000000`

Which gives me date from database ..

I want to group data in linq **BY Week**?

Can You help me?

Comment: Remember: `DateTime` hasn't format. What have you tried?

Comment: i have inserted data using Dateadd with code 104 so it has inserted default time for time part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Linq-To-Entities you can do:

```
source.GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", x.MeasurementDate));
```

Comment: Short and concise. Tested it in .Net 4.6 with Entity Framework 6, works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetWeekOfYear` method of the `Calendar` class

```
var dt = new List<DateTime?> { /*...*/ };
var dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
var ordered = dt
    .Where(x => x.HasValue)
    .OrderBy(x => dfi.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x.Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get the date of the first day in the week then group by that date.

To get the date of the first day in the week.
you can use this code:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

then you can group by the first date of the week like this:

```
source.GroupBy(i => i.MeasurementDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020982/linq-group-by-week-on-the-list/45039213#45039213)