# Linq - Group by week on the List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group by week my data like this:

```
var result = stats.GroupBy(i => SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", i.date))
            .Select(g => new ReportModel
            {
                clicks = g.Select(x => x.clicks).Sum(),
                impressions = g.Select(x => x.impressions).Sum(),
                ...
            });
```

But I get this error:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

What's the problem and how can I fixed it?

Comment: What is stats? Most likely it is in-memory list and not database query.

Comment: yes it's a list  in memory.

Comment: So that function cannot be used with such list, only as a part of database query.

Comment: `SqlFunctions`, as the class name suggests, contains methods to be used only when querying the database (using `EntityFramework`). They will not work with other LINQ sources.

Comment: You are executing a LINQ to Objects query, hence it has nothing to do with EF. Please remove the `entity-framework` tag and EF from the post title.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SqlFunctions.DatePart` (and other such functions) cannot be called as a regular method. It can only be used as a part of database query (with `IQueryable`). So you have to use another approach, for example:

```
stats.GroupBy(i => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
    i.date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Pay attention to the culture used and also parameters of `GetWeekOfYear` (what counts as first week of year and what counts as first day of week).

Comment: So, this statement will distinguish between first week of May in 2020 and first week of May in 2021, right ?

Answer (score 11):

Or you can get the date of the first day in the week then group by that date.

To get the date of the first day in the week.
you can use this code:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

then you can group by the first date of the week like this:

```
stats.GroupBy(i => i.date.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday));
```